# render javascript component (ag-grid) in r shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, ag-grid

I am trying to include the most basic example of ag-grid from their website in a R-shiny application, starting from there I will add more and more trying to setup a proper communication frontend-backend on data edit. However I am stuck at the basics of the inclusion. The component is included in source code but not rendered:

This is the basic example from ag-grid website:
https://plnkr.co/edit/nmWxAxWONarW5gj2?p=preview%3Fp%3Dpreview&preview

This is my R-Shiny application

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  #This tells shiny to include both css and scripts of aggrid
  tags$script(src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"),
  titlePanel("Ag-Grid Basic Example"),
  uiOutput("myGrid")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #This tells shiny to run our javascript file "script.js" and send it to the UI for rendering
  output$myGrid<- renderUI({
    HTML('<script type="text/javascript", src="script.js">  </script>')
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

where in www folder I have script.js that is a simple copy paste of the content of main.js from the example linked above.

```
const columnDefs = [
  { field: "make" },
  { field: "model" },
  { field: "price" }
];

// specify the data
const rowData = [
  { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
  { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
  { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000 }
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
});
```

Any hint on how to proceed?
The console is unfortunately not telling me anything relevant, css cdn and local script are read properly, but for some reasons it is not rendering the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't want to use something directly inside `renderUI` to directly modify the `uiOutput` container.
2. The table container must have some initial height and width.
3. Since this is loaded after the document is ready in a `renderUI` event, `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'` should not be used. Document will not be ready again, so this listener will not be triggered.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
ui <- fluidPage(
    #This tells shiny to include both css and scripts of aggrid
    tags$script(src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"),
    titlePanel("Ag-Grid Basic Example"),
    uiOutput("myGrid_container")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    #This tells shiny to run our javascript file "script.js" and send it to the UI for rendering
    output$myGrid_container<- renderUI({
        tagList(
            div(id = "myGrid", style="height: 200px; width:500px;", class="ag-theme-alpine"),
            tags$script(src="script.js")
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

```js
const columnDefs = [
  { field: "make" },
  { field: "model" },
  { field: "price" }
];

// specify the data
const rowData = [
  { make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000 },
  { make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000 },
  { make: "Porsche", model: "Boxster", price: 72000 }
];

// let the grid know which columns and what data to use
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  rowData: rowData
};

// setup the grid after the page has finished loading
const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);
```

[image]

Comment: looks great and very detailed, lots of findings, all good stuff to learn. thank you very much.